# MySQL Workbench not valid syntax

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am a rather simple trigger,

```
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER TRIGGER 'nfl`.`games_AFTER_INSERT` AFTER 
INSERT ON `games` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
 UPDATE nfl.teams t
 SET t.passingyards = t.passingyards +:new.homepassingyards,
     t.rushingyards = t.rushingyards +:new.homerushingyards
 WHERE t.teamname =:new.hometeamname;
END
```

however I keep getting a weird syntax error :

```
"+" is not valid at this position for this server version, expecting '-', '*', '/', '%', '<<','>>',...
```

I am running MySQL version 8.0.11 and the default storage engine of InnoDB. I searched the MySQL version and triggers are supported by this version so I'm quite lost here. Is this a problem with how the trigger is declared at the top? I'm not used to the syntax "CREATE DEFINER" and thought this might be the problem however it is what is generated by MySQL Workbench when you try to create a new trigger.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you have colons (`:`) in front of variables ? These are not prepared statements, which you are trying to execute. You need to remove those colons.

Comment: :new is oracle syntax MySQL does not have :

Comment: Ah thank you, too familiar with Oracle and it shows! Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

A simple syntax error, beside the leading colons, which have to be removed. You used different quotes for your first `nfl` occurance. Here's the correct form:

```
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER TRIGGER `nfl`.`games_AFTER_INSERT` AFTER INSERT ON `games` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
 UPDATE nfl.teams t
 SET t.passingyards = t.passingyards + new.homepassingyards,
     t.rushingyards = t.rushingyards + new.homerushingyards
 WHERE t.teamname = new.hometeamname;
END
```